# Теряется this обработчика событий в классе

Tags: javascript, html

В консоли пишет null у обработчика события. Нечто похожее витает на стаке, но сделав все также контекст все равно теряется. Уже думаю просто отдельно через цикл написать функцию за границами класса, либо на крайняк повесить onchange селекту в innerHtml

```
class Selector {
   constructor(parentSelector, id){
     this.parentSelector = parentSelector;
     this.itemResult = document.querySelector(`#itemresult_${id}`);
     this.itemSelect = document.querySelector(`#itemselect_${id}`);
     this.clickHandler = this.clickHandler.bind(this);
     this.bindEvents();
   }
   
   bindEvents() {
       this.itemResult.addEventListener('click', this.clickHandler)
   }

   clickHandler() {
       this.itemResult.textContent = this.itemSelect.value * 25;
   }

   render() {
      const ol = document.createElement('ol');
      ol.innerHtml = `
        <li>
          <select name="itemselect_${this.id}" id="itemselect_${this.id}">
               <option value="0">0</option>
               <option value="1">1</option>
               <option value="2">2</option>
               <option value="3">3</option>
          </select>
        </li><li>&#43;<span id="itemresult_${this.id}" class="itemresult">0</span>&#37;</li>
      `
      this.parentSelector.append(ol);   
   }
}
```

Comment: `this.itemResult.addEventListener('click', this.clickHandler.bind(this))`

Comment: `this.itemResult.addEventListener('click', (e) => this.clickHandler(e))`

Comment: все равно теряется контекст, Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener')

Comment: @LuckyBunny, проверь наличие `document.querySelector(`#itemselect_${id}`);`. Возможно этого элемента просто нет на момент создания экземпляра класса и `this.itemResult` равен `null`...

Comment: Эта ошибка абсолютно никак не связана с потерей контекста...

Comment: да, проверил через условие, ошибка возникала потому что `this.itemResult` не был еще отрисован, буду плясать от этого, спасибо за напутствие